# How to install/compile lgmask on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, installation, libjpeg

I am trying to install Gmask software form source for Ubuntu: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lgmask/

Normally I can run the following to make this happen:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

but for the aforementioned package there's no configure directory so this does not work =(

Comment: A GNU Make and Autotools project has well defined installation directories. Also see [GNU Make | Variables for Installation Directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html). If they are missing or not honored, then you should consider filing a bug report.

Comment: I'll just mention here that a work around to my specific problem is to use the GIMP Mask plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this tarball does come with a Makefile, you can see `make install` will install lgmask into /usr/local/bin

```
cat Makefile 
all: gmask umask
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O2 -fms-extensions

gmask: libimg/jpeg.o masks.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lgmask.c -o lgmask -lX11 -ljpeg libimg/jpeg.o masks.o

umask: libimg/jpeg.o masks.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) unmask.c -o unmask -Wall -ljpeg masks.o libimg/jpeg.o

clean:
    rm -f ?*~ libimg/*.o *.o

install: all
    install lgmask /usr/local/bin
```

The author did not include the dependency libimg/* in the tarball... I searched around and found it in his svn repo:

```
sudo apt-get subversion
svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/lgmask/code/trunk lgmask-code
```

now, this code depends on libjpeg, let's install it

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

from where you checkout the source code:

```
cd libimg
gcc -c jpeg.c -ljpeg
cd ..
gcc -O2 -fms-extensions lgmask.c -o lgmask -L/usr/lib libimg/jpeg.o masks.o -ljpeg -lX11
```

you will get some warnings but it will compile lgmask for you

```
~/tmp/lgmask-code$ ./lgmask 
usage: lgmask <image name>
```

Unfortunately when I tried to run it with several jpeg, it pops up a blank image... I tried to compile it with different version libjpeg but get the same result, let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: hi runwuf thanks for your reply!

I tried typing "sudo make install" and here's what I get:

`sudo make install
gcc -O2 -fms-extensions   -c -o libimg/jpeg.o libimg/jpeg.c
libimg/jpeg.c:8:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'libimg/jpeg.o' failed
make: *** [libimg/jpeg.o] Error 1 `

Comment: Hi @LostCrotchet sorry I missed your comment.  I just updated the answer, give it a try, good luck!